Build jenkins pipeline on PR creation
I create a small project for testing building a workflow on PR creation. I follow this tuto: Tuto
I have two branches. Each has a Jenkinsfile
main Jenkinsfile:
pipeline {
agent any

environment {
    VENV_PATH = "${env.WORKSPACE}/../env_venv"
    PYTHON_PATH = "/usr/bin/python3.10"
}

stages {

    stage('Preparation') {
        steps {
            // Clean the workspace to ensure no residual files from previous builds
            deleteDir()
            // Checkout the latest code from the Source Control Management (SCM) system
            checkout scm
        }
    }

    stage('Create Virtual Environment') {
        steps {
            echo "Create environment in main branch"
        }
    }
    }
    }

branchA Jenkinsfile:
pipeline {
agent any

environment {
    VENV_PATH = "${env.WORKSPACE}/../env_venv"
    PYTHON_PATH = "/usr/bin/python3.10"
}

stages {

    stage('Preparation') {
        steps {
            // Clean the workspace to ensure no residual files from previous builds
            deleteDir()
            // Checkout the latest code from the Source Control Management (SCM) system
            checkout scm
        }
    }

    stage('Create Virtual Environment') {
        steps {
            script{
                if (env.BITBUCKET_PULL_REQUEST_ID){
                    echo "pull request!"
                }
                else{
                    echo "Push"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    
    }
    }

Jenkins pipeline configuration:



Webhook on bitbucket:

I created a PR to merge BranchA on main. The workflow does not start. I am not sure what I did wrong here?
